# Keras LSTM multi-dimension input

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, theano, keras, recurrent-neural-network

my input time series data is of the shape (nb_samples, 75, 32).
75 is the timesteps and 32 is the input dimension.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(75, 32)))
model.summary()
```

The LSTM weight vectors,`[W_i, W_c, W_f, W_o]` are all 32 dimensions, but the output is just a single value. the output shape of the above model is (1,4). But in LSTM the output is also a vector so should not it be (32,4) for many to one implementation as above? why is it giving a single value for multi-dimension input also?

Comment: What do you mean by that this vectors have 32 dimensions? It's not true.

Answer (score 5):

As you can read in the [Keras doc for reccurent layers](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/)

For an input of shape `(nb_sample, timestep, input_dim)`, you have two possible outputs:

- if you set `return_sequence=True` in your LSTM (which is not your case), you return every hidden state, so the intermediate steps when the LSTM 'reads' your sequence. You get an output of shape `(nb_sample, timestep, output_dim)`.
- if you set `return_sequence=False` (which is the default), it will only output the last state. So you will get an output of shape `(nb_sample, output_dim)`.

So if you define your LSTM layer like this :

```
model.add(LSTM(4, return_sequence=True, input_shape=(75, 32)))
```

you will have an output of shape `(None, 75, 4)`. If 32 is your time dimension, you will have to transpose the data before feeding it to the LSTM. The first dimension is the temporal one.

I hope this helps :)